# Bootstrap collapse not hidden by default?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to make a little modification to a webpage that is using bootstrap to hide some data that is shown after clicking a button. I want to make this info not hidden by default.
How can I do that?

```
<a class="showInfo btn btn-sm btn-warning" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#data_<?php echo $row->data_id ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="data_<?php echo $row->data_id ?>">Show Info</a>
```

Comment: Show your whole HTML code (including collapsible div).

Comment: FOUND IT!!! I take out collapse from :<div class="containerInfo collapse" id="data_<?php echo $row->data_id ?>">

Answer (score 0):

Remove "collapse" from

```
<div class="containerInfo collapse" id="data_<?php echo $row->data_id ?>">
```